# Textstroke rendering problem with M letters

Tags: svg, render, echarts

I have an echart with a serie type:'custom' and I have a rendering issues on the labels.
I return this

```
return {
type: 'group',
children: [
  {
    type: 'rect',
    ignore: !rectNormal,
    shape: rectNormal,
    style:  { stroke: '#707070' }
  },
  {
    type: 'rect',
    ignore: !rectText,
    shape: rectText,
    strokeLinejoin: "round",
    stroke: 'trasparent',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    style: api.style({
      fill: 'transparent',
      fontWeight: bigText? 600 : 100,
      fontSize: bigText? 15 : 10,

      textStroke: '#707070',
      strokeLinejoin: "round",
      strokeLinecap: "round",
      textStrokeWidth: 3,
   
      text: text,
      textFill: '#ffffff'
    })
  }
]
```

And it' rendered like this
[image]

As you can see the text stroke have problem in rendering the M letters and the strokeLinejoin and strokeLinecap did not solve the problem.

Do someone know how to fix this?

Comment: It seems to be a render bug but you can try to use [zRender option](https://ecomfe.github.io/zrender-doc/public/api.html#zrenderdisplayable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I solved it this way 


  {
    type: 'rect',
    ignore: !rectText,
    shape: rectText,
    strokeLinejoin: "round",
    stroke: 'trasparent',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    style: api.style({
      fill: 'transparent',
      fontWeight: bigText? 600 : 100,
      fontSize: bigText? 15 : 10,

      textStroke: '#707070',
      lineJoin: "bevel",
      textStrokeWidth: 3,
   
      text: text,
      textFill: '#ffffff'
    })
  }
```